# SSIS Data flow task runs by itself but not as part of package

Tags: c#, json, ssis

I have a dtsx package which contains a bunch of data flows.

All of them select rows from table, each of the rows contains a column with some JSON, there is a script component (C#) which deserializes the JSON, then a data destination which loads the data up to some buffer tables.

One of the most simple scripts which deals with some really simple JSON runs perfectly by itself (Right click -> Execute Task, or when all other tasks are disabled), however when I try to run the package as a whole this package falls over with the error message

Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at ScriptMain.Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
   at UserComponent.Input0_ProcessInput(Input0Buffer Buffer)
   at UserComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, String InputName, PipelineBuffer Buffer, OutputNameMap OutputMap)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponent.ProcessInput(Int32 InputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ScriptComponentHost.ProcessInput(Int32 inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)

The JSON looks like this...

```
{
"token": "0b683877-81d6-4dhs-a1ad-9fcfff6acb61",
"email": "someone@gmail.com"
}
```

and the c# like this

```
public class RootAttributes
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    String myEvtData = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Row.evtdata.GetBlobData(0, Convert.ToInt32(Row.evtdata.Length)));
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    RootAttributes jRow = js.Deserialize<RootAttributes>(myEvtData);

    //DB Output
    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
    Output0Buffer.country = Row.country;
    Output0Buffer.ord = Row.ord;
    Output0Buffer.aggregateversion = Row.aggregateversion;
    Output0Buffer.clienttype = Row.clienttype;
    Output0Buffer.aggregateid = Row.aggregateid;
    Output0Buffer.updby = Row.updby;
    Output0Buffer.evttimestamp = Row.evttimestamp;
    //JSON Output
    Output0Buffer.token = jRow.token;
    Output0Buffer.email = jRow.email;
}
```

I have a second script - virtually identical which also fails with the same error message. I have tried running them both one after the other and independently - i.e. all DFs at once.

Please help

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you are just adding those two columns, then you don't need:

```
//DB Output
    Output0Buffer.AddRow();
    Output0Buffer.country = Row.country;
    Output0Buffer.ord = Row.ord;
    Output0Buffer.aggregateversion = Row.aggregateversion;
    Output0Buffer.clienttype = Row.clienttype;
    Output0Buffer.aggregateid = Row.aggregateid;
    Output0Buffer.updby = Row.updby;
    Output0Buffer.evttimestamp = Row.evttimestamp;
```

Just add the two columns to the Output0Buffer.

You just need to check the one column that has the JSON on the middle page.

Comment: Thanks - I will need those columns for various processing tasks later on in the solution. All the dataflows that run have these columns too.

Comment: You don't lose them. They pass through without any edit.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this was due to copying Data Flow tasks from one package to another. I am not 100% sure what the cause is, but copying wasn't perfect and the DFs seemed to be infecting each other.

I found the solution here

https://kohera.be/blog/sql-server/the-dangers-of-copying-script-components-in-ssis/